# NetworkXError: The node osmid is not in the digraph

Tags: networkx

The upgrades of OSMNX and NetworkX have rendered some codes not to be working and having some difficulty in comprehending the documentation to resolve the issue.

Running the below code resulted in the error code of NetworkXError: The node osmid is not in the digraph at line of nx.neighbors(G, n)

Hope to get some advice on it.

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

G= ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='drive')
inter = ox.consolidate_intersections(ox.project_graph(G))
nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(inter, edges=False)

connections = {}

for n in nodes:
    connections[n] = set([])
    for nbr in nx.neighbors(G, n):
        connections[n].add(str(G.get_edge_data(n, nbr).get(0).get('name')))
```

Comment: Can you flesh out what you're trying to do here? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Managed to resolve it. The issue is due to missing a line to compute for "get_nearest_node"  to get the nodes. There was an earlier confusion of the use of the term nodes. The intent is to get the XY/LatLon from consolidate_intersections and the corresponding street names through a left joint by nodes information.